# How to get Committed Memory in Windows Server 2012 using .NET

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management, ram

This is how I get the total and used RAM:

```
PerformanceCounter ramAvailableCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Available MBytes");
var ramUsedMB = ramAvailableCounter.NextValue();

var ramTotalMB = new Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.ComputerInfo().TotalPhysicalMemory / 1024 / 1024;

var ramPercentageLeft = (ramUsedMB * 100) / ramTotalMB;
```

But how can I get the "Committed" memory shown below? 

Unfortunately the application we use throws an exception when there is only about 15GB free and I would like to send a notification when is close enough.

[image]

Comment: Why would *anything* throw an exception when there is 15 GB of memory free? Even putting aside the reality of virtual memory, that makes absolutely no sense. Exceptions are for when an error occurred. 15 GB is not a hard out-of-memory error even for the most demanding of applications. Anyway, you aren't going to beat a badly-designed application by trying to out-guess it. Just catch the bone-headed exception and handle it.

Comment: @CodyGray thanks...It's BI application which handles hundreds of millions of records. So 15GB is not enough, it actually uses around 45GB to perform a full reload ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done as following:

```
PerformanceCounter percCommittedBytesInUseCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Memory", "% Committed Bytes In Use");
```